# I want to set region for Firebase Functions in nodeJS project

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

While creating a project, I selected the region **asia-south1**, but I am surprised when I deploy the functions URL started from **us-central1**

I want to know, What is the current region for my firebase function, I want to set it as **asia-south1**.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find how to change a GCF region in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations):

> **By default, functions run in the us-central1 region.** Note that this
> may be different from the region of an event source, such as a Cloud
> Storage bucket. If you need to change the region where a function
> runs, follow the recommendations in this section for each function
> trigger type.
>
> To set the region where a function runs, set the region parameter in
> the function definition as shown:
>
> ```
> exports.myStorageFunction = functions
>     .region('asia-south1')
>     .storage
>     .object()
>     .onFinalize((object) => {
>       // ...
>     });
> ```
>
> You can specify multiple regions by passing multiple comma-separated
> region strings in functions.region().

Comment: Thank you for answering, I want to know why my URL started from us-central1 even my GCF location is asia-south1 ?

Comment: Because as the doc states, by default, functions run in the us-central1 region, regardless your project location.